How can I replace values in array of struct with another values using spark?
I have a hive table named student_details, it has the below format:
| Date       | Name       | Age | Subject | Students                                                                                                                                                         | Report Date |

|------------|------------|-----|---------|------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|--------------|

| 2024-04-17 | John Doe   | 15 | Math    | [{id: null, grade: "A", score: null, attendance: true, behaviour: "Good"}, {id: null, grade: "B", score: null, attendance: true, behaviour: "Average"}]        | 2024-04-17   |

| 2024-04-17 | Jane Smith | 14 | Science | [{id: null, grade: "A", score: null, attendance: true, behaviour: "Excellent"}, {id: null, grade: "B", score: null, attendance: true, behaviour: "Good"}, {id: null, grade: "C", score: null, attendance: false, behaviour: "Poor"}] | 2024-04-17   |

| 2024-04-17 | Tom Brown | 16 | English | [{id: null, grade: "B", score: null, attendance: true, behaviour: "Average"}]                                                                                     | 2024-04-17   |

This is the schema of the above table:
root
 |-- Date: date (nullable = true)
 |-- Name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Age: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- Subject: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Students: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- id: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- grade: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- score: double (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- attendance: boolean (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- behaviour: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Report Date: date (nullable = true)



As you can see there are null values in array of struct(Students) for "id" and "score", I want to fill those null values with zero, this is just an example of data I have, actually I have more than 80 columns, I want spark scala code for this or even a hive query is also fine, one thing is if I am trying to group them in hive after exploding that Students column, I am getting error like cannot group more than 64 columns. I have spark version 2.3.2, I guess even transform function won't work. The table is partitioned by "Report Date". The above data is only for a particular report date '2024-04-17', after I make changes how can I save this data to a hive table.
How can I do all this either through spark scala or Hive ?
I tried to create a udf function in through spark scala but I am missing somewhere, I used transform function but isn't working maybe because of version. I exploded it and made changes but when I am using collect_list() for the exploded struct, I need to group them right by using remaining all columns, but there is a max limit for grouping which is 64, but I have more than that. I think I can't simply group using only key columns as it needs every other column.
